# How to display background image in h:body tag with CSS in jsf

Tags: html, css, image, jsf, background-image

i have a image of size 250 x 25

i want to display in page background with repeat-x and repeat-y

but below is not working

```
<h:body styel="background: url(/Images/logoback.jpg) repeat-x repeat- y >
```

Answer (score 2):

Too many mistakes

- `style` and not `styel`
- Not closing `"` double quote
- And if you want to repeat horizontally as well as vertically just use `repeat` after `background-image`..
- Always use a semi-colon at end of each `propery: value;`
  Try this